# Difference between "aufschreiben" and "mitschreiben"?

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context, verb-usage, verb-choice

In my book I have come across both the verbs *"aufschreiben"* and *"mitschreiben"*. A simple google translate tells that both of the verbs mean ***"To write down"***.

**My question is/are**: -

- When to use which verb?
- How will I know which verb to use if they both mean the same?
- Any specific difference between them?

Can you also please give examples in form of a sentence for better understanding of their usage.

Comment: Google Translate is the wrong way to look up words. It only offers one possible translation and that may be wrong, not even depending on context. An alternative is [dict.cc](http://dict.cc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> aufschreiben

- record by writing or also write down e.g. your observations, your thoughts
- write down e.g. *I wrote down the cell phone number*

> mitschreiben:

- listen to something and write it down at the same time e.g. *take down the lecture*

Comment: the last example should be not conjoined, right, specificly to mark the difference??

Comment: "**prescribe sth**" is "etwas verschreiben**" so this example is wrong

"**take part in a written test**" is "**einen Test schreiben**" 
You can say "**einen Test mitschreiben**", but this more likely means you manage to participate in a test (there where some obstacles to overcome)

Comment: @masatwwo - thanks for the hints - edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although not an exact translation, cp. En. "to write *up*" (summarize, notice; list).

The connotatiin in *auf* "on" completely subsumes that and leaves nothing but the denotional sense, "onto [paper]; [to write] down", at first sight, although the usage is still very much within the realm of drafting a *record*.

*Mitschreiben* is used chiefly in the denotional sense, too, i.e. "along, in synchrony"; cp. eg. *mit fahren, mitkommen. The etymologic connection to Greek *meta* might imply something more, and Lat. *mit-* "to send" (cf. *message*) might be informative on top of that, however long forgotten if that were the case, not evident from usage at all. Compare nonetheless *Mitteilung* to that effect; not here: vermitteln* (cf. *middle*, *mediate*); probably not here: *mitgeben*, cp. *Mitgift* "dowry" opposite of "brideprice" (again there's a Greek comparison, viz. "to pay", iirc). Since *auf* can mean "on top of", a sense like "add to [a listing, chrinical, etc.]" also comes to mind, e.g. in police lingo: to write somebody a notice for a misdemeanor, but colloquially paraphrased when a particular listing is concerned, e.g. *dazuschreiben*.

At that it's notable that writing used to be a special craft with idiosyncratic terminology.

However it came to be today the main difference is that ***Mitschrift* requires a lecture or other non-written source to copy from.**

Whereas *aufschreiben* may be creative, perhaps spontanious, and so generally applicable that it is not specialized enough to have a corresponding result noun. There's only a superficial comparison in *Aufschrift*(cp. *Überschrift, Untertitel, Inschrift*). One might contrast *Abschrift*, that has very narrow usage in law denoting legal copy of a writ, next to *ausfertigung* with a similar sense but different legal requirements (*ex perfection*?).. Another connotation of *aufschreiben* (of debts, guilts) can be contrasted with *abschreiben* "to write off" (cp. *streichen* "to strike, erase from a list", refl. *sich ein-/ausschreiben* in university "im-/exmatrikulate"). Whereas the connotation of originality can be contrasted with another sense of *abschreiben*, that is "to write off of, cheat by copying, immitate".

Compare by the way: English *copy-editing* (a genre of advertising text, very descriptive)? *Auftrag* "task, mission" also " coating, layer on-top"? *Annonce* "(ad) copy" versus *announce*? *Apostal*, *apocryphe*, *apo-*, *post* (lol what?), En. *off*, irregular Ger. *uff* "up, on" from *op, cp. *hör auf* "stop" (listen up; leave it), contrast *weg* "away, off", note *auf-g'-* (*i.e. pastpart. *aufgeschrieben*)? *fax*, from *facsimile*, *fac-* "do" + *simil(ar)*, suppletive present tense of *fio*, future "to be(come)", cf. *(last) will*? cp. *of-ficial*???